# Apache Log4j in Android gives exception java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/log4j/config/PropertySetter

Tags: android, exception, logging, log4j, flickr

I am trying to integrate Flickr in android using the [Flickr4Java](https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java) library. Flickr4Java uses Log4j for logging. So when I try to create an instance of flickr, something like `Flickr flickr = new Flickr(apiKey, sharedSecret, new REST());` I get the following stack trace

```
05-12 01:24:28.714    8449-8449/edu.sdsu.cs.sharepic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.sdsu.cs.sharepic, PID: 8449
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/log4j/config/PropertySetter
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:805)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
        at com.flickr4java.flickr.REST.<clinit>(REST.java:46)
        at edu.sdsu.cs.sharepic.model.Flickr1.<init>(Flickr1.java:28)
        at edu.sdsu.cs.sharepic.activity.SelectProfileActivity.init(SelectProfileActivity.java:75)
        at edu.sdsu.cs.sharepic.activity.SelectProfileActivity.onCreate(SelectProfileActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am guessing it has got something to do with configuration of the log4j library, but don't know how to solve the problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j uses apis from java.beans that is missing in android.
Try this library https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-logging-log4j/
I have yet to look at it tough